# AJAX load not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, ajax

I am trying to update a marquee in html based on data from an external php file data, conditional on database changes.

My code below is not working.

**HTML**

```
<p class="scroll marquee"><span></span></p>
```

The above tag should only be updated if there are any recent changes in the database.

**Checking for recent changes in php**

```
<?php
require_once('connect.php');

$json = []; // The JSON array which will be returned
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT( * ) AS count
FROM `mallscrolls` 
LEFT JOIN malls ON malls.m_Id = mallscrolls.`M-Ids` 
WHERE mallname = 'C Mall' && time_insert > NOW( ) - INTERVAL 25 
SECOND ");
$stmt ->execute();
$row = $stmt ->fetch();
$update = $row['count'] > 0;
$updtstatus =  json_encode(array('count'=>$update));
?>
```

**Ajax will check every few seconds for updates**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function scrollhandler() {
$.getJSON("check_time_scroll.php", function(update) {
    if (update.count===true) {
     $('#scroll marquee').load('unifoscrolltext.php');
    } 
});
}
setInterval(scrollhandler, 10000);
</script>
```

**'unifoscrolltext.php'**

```
<?php
require_once('connect.php');
$stme= $conn->prepare("SELECT message
FROM `mallscrolls` 
LEFT JOIN malls ON malls.m_Id = mallscrolls.`M-Ids` 
WHERE mallname = 'C Mall' && time_insert > NOW( ) - INTERVAL 30 
MINUTE");
$stme->execute();
while($resultst = $stme-> fetch()){
$message = $resultst["message"];
echo "$message";
}
?>
```

**CSS**

```
<style>
/* Make it a marquee */
.marquee {
width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #000000;
bottom: 0px;
```

}

```
.marquee span {
display: inline-block;
padding-left: 100%;
text-indent: 0;
animation: marquee 20s linear infinite;
background-color: #000000;
color: white;
bottom: 0px;
}

/* Make it move */
@keyframes marquee {
0%   { transform: translate(0, 0); }
100% { transform: translate(-100%, 0); }
}

/* Make it pretty */
.scroll {
padding-left: 1.5em;
position: fixed;
font: 50px 'Verdana';
bottom: 0px;
left: 0px;
height: 10%;
}
</style>
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you watched the AJAX request/response in the browser's console?